# Selecting conserved residues in protein using PyMol script by importing residue list from a text file

Tags: python, bioinformatics, pymol

I wanted to select certain highly conserved residues in a protein (computed by a scoring mechanism and listed in a text file - each residue in a single line) using a PyMol script. The PyMol script below that I am using is not working. I will be very grateful to you if someone could help me out.

Parts of the script work perfectly fine when run separately - the Pymol script when a residue number is mentioned in the script without importing the list from the text file and just the python script for loading numbers from a file into an array also works fine when run separately. But the problem is seen when it is combined as in my script below - when residue number needs to be taken from the array as i after importing the list from the text file. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from pymol import cmd
import string
cmd.load("/home/xyz/proteinA.pdb", 'protein')

f=open('/home/xyz/residuedata.txt','r')
array = []
filecontents = f.read().split()
for val in filecontents:
        array.append(int(val))
f.close()
for i in array:
    cmd.select("residuedata", "resi i")
    cmd.show('sphere', "residuedata")
    cmd.color ('red', "residuedata")
```

Comment: you should ask biostars http://www.biostars.org/show/questions/

Answer (score 1):

The `"resi i"` string does not know about your `i` variable.

Did you intend to do this?

```
for i in array:
    cmd.select("residuedata", "resi {}".format(i))
```